# Is the return type of this method a slice or a borrowed array?

Tags: arrays, vector, types, rust, slice

I am working through the Rust book, specifically the "Departments" exercise in section 8.3.

I've become a little confused by what is being returned from a method I've created.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
enum Department {
    Sales,
    Engineering,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Company {
    users: HashMap<Department, Vec<String>>,
}

impl Company {
    fn add_user_to_department(&mut self, department: Department, employee: String) {
        let users = self.users.entry(department).or_insert(Vec::new());
        users.push(employee);
    }

    fn get_users_in_department(&self, department: Department) -> &[String] {
        match self.users.get(&department) {
            Some(u) => &u,
            None => &[]
        }
    }
}
```

At first I thought the method `get_users_in_department` is returning a slice of the `Vec` (or in the case of `None` a static literal).

But in my `match` statement I am not using the slice syntax, I am returning a borrowed reference to the `Vec`.

```
match self.users.get(&department) {
    Some(u) => &u,
    None => &[]
}
```

If I was returning a slice wouldn't I have to return `Some(u) => &u[..],`

I guess my confusion boils down to what the return type of  `get_users_in_department` is. Is it returning a reference to an array of `String`, or a slice of an array of `String`. Are these two types interchangeable due to some sort of coercion? If it's possible to differentiate between the two, how and when would I want to return one or the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From *Type Coercions* in The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html):

> Type coercions are implicit operations that change the type of a value. They happen automatically at specific locations and are highly restricted in what types actually coerce.

> Coercion is allowed between the following types:
>
> - `&T` or `&mut T` to `&U` if `T` implements `Deref<Target = U>`.

This kind of type coercion is called a *deref coercion*. Relevant example: `Vec<T>` implements `Deref<Target = [T]>` so `&Vec<T>` can be coerced into `&[T]`.

> A coercion can only occur at certain coercion sites in a program; these are typically places where the desired type is explicit or can be derived by propagation from explicit types (without type inference). Possible coercion sites are:
>
> - Function results—either the final line of a block if it is not semicolon-terminated or any expression in a return statement.

Example:

```rust
// no type coercion
fn vec_to_vec<T>(vec: &Vec<T>) -> &Vec<T> {
    vec
}

// &Vec<T> coerced to &[T] via deref coercion
fn vec_to_slice<T>(vec: &Vec<T>) -> &[T] {
    vec
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=50db1db2c111de75d477dbec4466216b)

To answer your question more directly, the type of `&u` inside `get_users_in_department` is `&Vec<String>` but it's being coerced into `&[String]` by the compiler for you.

Comment: Isn't it a bit confusing to write "the return type of `get_users_in_department` is `&Vec<String>`" when there is `-> &[String]` clearly visible in the posted code? Wouldn't it be better to say: "the return type of `get_users_in_department` is `&[String]`  (a slice reference) since that's what's written in the code, and here's how that's possible"?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've updated my answer to be more clear.